Print sentence not working in form_load ( Visual Studio 6.0 )?
I have installed Visual Basic 6 on my Windows 11, but I have a problem..the print statement in the "Form_load" is not working
I tried it inside CommandButton, it worked
but inside the form_load it didn't work..is the problem with the program?
Please help

You can't print on a form while it's in the process of loading! It's a bit like trying to write on a piece of paper that is still being made.

Incidentally, Visual Basic/Studio 6 is not the same as VB6 which is a much earlier version and went out of support in around 1990. My comment applies to both, but which one are you actually using?

@JohnEason: now you're confusing me. For all I know VB6 is short for Visual Basic 6, which is the Visual Basic version that comes with Visual Studio 6. So whether you bought the standalone version of VB6 or Visual Studio 6, you'd end up with the same Visual Basic 6, wouldn't you?

I've always assumed that Visual Studio versions of VB were .net-based and therefore a different language. I bought mine long before Visual Studio existed so I'm probably not up to date with version numbers.

Set the forms AutoRedraw property to True and you can print in _Load.

@Alex K.  Thank you very much..it works now
